# Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1 with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, composer-php

Hi I work on a macbook and use `Xampp` and I have a problem on my `laravel` project 5.4. When I do `composer update` I had this error:

`In Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from houses)`

`In Connector.php line 68: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

Script `php artisan optimize` handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1.

I don't know how to resolve that I check the user of my database it's root, I check my `.env` in my `laravel` project the `name`, `user` and `password` are ok, I can access to `phpmyadmin`, I imported the database file on `phpmyadmin`. And when I do `php artisan serve`

I have this error:

`In Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from houses)`

`In Connector.php line 68: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

But I think it's normal because the composer update didn't worked.

Comment: Did you try it by cleanup cache? somewhere db connection is not setup properly that's the reason you are getting this error. Have you check database.php file also? Make sure db credentials are called from env file in this file.

Answer (score 0):

First clear cache if any changes was made in `.env`:

```
php artisan config:cache
```